# c# random number generator for multiple forms in one solution.

Tags: c#

I am very new to programming and I am working on a project for school in Visual Studio but I am kinda stuck. I have multiple forms in my solution. One of my forms is an invoice and I am trying to create an invoice number when the checkout button on the previous form is clicked. I have the following code in the textBox field that I want to display my number but the number is not showing in the textBox. Please help!!

```
    private void txtBoxInvoiceNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rndNo = new Random();
        int invoiceNo = rndNo.Next(1, 500);
        txtInvoiceNo.Text = invoiceNo.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: What's really your question?

Comment: You need that code in the event for the checkbox being clicked, not the event for the text in that textbox changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to utilize something on multiple forms you better Add a `Class` and write a method which will return integer. Refer below sample

```
Public class GenerateNumber
{
    public static int GetRandomNo()
    {
        Random rndNo = new Random();
        int invoiceNo = rndNo.Next(1, 500);
        return invoiceNo;
    }
}
```

Then you can make object of class and call this function on the required form. Refer Below code

```
GenerateNumber randomNo = new GenerateNo();
txtInvoiceNo.Text = randomNo.GetRandomNo().ToString()
```

Comment: I think the problem with the OP code is that they're not calling the code in the correct location, not that they can't generate a random number.

Comment: He needs to generate a random number from inside `checkoutButton_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)`, not `txtBoxInvoiceNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)`. I can't be 100% positive, but I'm pretty sure that's the only problem with the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to see a bit more code here, but from what you have shown it suggests you are generating the invoice number on the textChanged event of txtBoxInvoiceNo.  This event will fire when the text changes within that box.  Not on creation of the form.

My suggestion would be to call a function on construction of your form.  The code you have written should work, it just needs to be called in the right place.

I'm assuming you're writing winforms but something like:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GenerateInvoiceNumber();
}

private void GenerateInvoiceNumber()
{
    Random rndNo = new Random();
    int invoiceNo = rndNo.Next(1, 500);
    txtInvoiceNo.Text = invoiceNo.ToString();
}
```

You can refactor this later into a static or extension method so it can be used by multiple forms, but the call should be made in the constructor, not in a text box changed event.